# Ajax request is too slow using Yii2 Framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, yii2

```
$(function () {
    $('#barcode-form').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?= Url::to(['/sales/cart-barcode']) ?>',
        data: $('#barcode-form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $( '#barcode-form' ).each(function(){this.reset();});
            document.getElementById("pcode").focus();
        }
      });
    });
});
```

This is the jQuery AJAX function and it's working well but it's taking about 2700ms and that is not acceptable by any customer.

```
<form  id="barcode-form">
    <?php
    $a=array();
    foreach ($productsAvailable as $product){      
        array_push($a,$product->product_code);
    }

    echo TypeaheadBasic::widget([
        'name' => 'pcode',
         'id' => 'pcode',
        'data' =>  $a,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
    ]); 
    ?> 
    <input type="submit" hidden/>
</form>
```

At the backend I am getting the data of the AJAX request and edit my table as shown in this action:

```
public function actionCartBarcode() {
    $request = Yii::$app->request;

    $productCode = $request->getBodyParam('pcode');



    $invoice = Invoice::find()->where(['status' => 1])->one();
    $invoiceId = $invoice->invoice_id;
    $product = AppProduct::find()->where(['product_code' => $productCode])->one();
    $productId = $product->product_id;
    //first see if product exist (change sales to cart after you create the cart table)
    $model = Sales::find()->where(['r_product_id' => $productId])->andWhere(['r_invoice_id' => $invoiceId])->one();
    if ($model) {
        $model->sold_product_qty += 1;
    } else {

        $model = new Sales();
        $model->r_invoice_id = $invoiceId;
        $model->r_product_id = $productId;
        $model->sold_product_qty = 1;
        $model->discount = 0;
        $model->price_per_unit = $product->product_price;
        $model->total_price = $product->product_price;
        $model->profit = $product->product_price - $product->product_cost;
    }
    if ($model->save()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        VarDumper::dump($productId, 10, true);
        die();
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: you tell us your ajax request is slow - but you don't show us your server side code which is executed by the ajax post request - so it's hard to find a performance issue

Comment: i have edited my code ,take a look

Comment: your queries could be slow depending in how many entries Sales/Invoice/AppProduct Table contains - but you need to debug it more deeply (e.g. check with `microtime` how long each action takes) - 
some other input - does it make sense to get the first Invoice? - should it not be user specific?

Comment: yes in my case it is not necessary to be user specific, i debug the actions it seems that reloading the cart div is taking about 1.5 seconds, to display the new contents in my html frontend  i am using pjax reload  $.pjax.reload({container: '#cart-pjax', async: false});

Comment: If there is any possibility, join all or few queries and build one query (it will reduce query compilation & exec time). Plus, check each model related lines execution time; in order to understand which part consuming more time..! Eg - `$time_start = microtime(true); $invoice = Invoice::find()->where(['status' => 1])->one(); echo $time_end = microtime(true) - $time_start;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some [profiling](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-performance-tuning#performance-profiling) to find part of the code which is slow. At this point the only thing that you can get here is blind guess.

---

But here is my shot:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find()->where(['status' => 1])->one();
```

You should be really careful with this. `one()` does not set any limit in query implicitly. It means that if you have 1 million invoices with `status` equal to `1`, this will load them all to PHP and pick only first one and ignore everything else. This can create noticeable but not obvious overhead, since all these additional 999999 records must be found by DBMS and send to PHP process. When you're using `one()` with non-unique fields in where, you should set limit explicitly:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find()->where(['status' => 1])->limit(1)->one();
```

Comment: In my case I will always have only one invoice with status =1